# Including categorical features in Elasticsearch LTR

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch LTR plugin to train an sltr model. I have 3 features in my feature set, 2 are numerical and the other is categorical which has around 100 unique categories. I have included the numerical features like below and I am not sure how to include the cat feature. If I encode it and include in the below format I am guessing the model would treat it as a numerical feature which I do not want. Any help here please

````
  "validation": {
    "index": "my-index",
    "params": {
    }
  },
  "featureset": {
    "features": [
      {
        "name": "feat1",
        "params":[],
        "template": {
          "function_score": {
            "field_value_factor": {
              "field": "feat1",
              "missing":0
            },
            "query": {
              "match_all": {}
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "feat2",
        "template": {
          "function_score": {
            "field_value_factor": {
              "field": "feat2",
              "missing":0
            },
            "query": {
              "match_all": {}
            }
          }
        }
      }```
````

Comment: the LTR plugin needs a query per feature, you could one hot encode your categorical feature and continue following the pattern you are using of storing the document values in new fields `feat3_1 ... feat3_100`

Comment: That's the problem here. The categorical feature has more than 100 unique values.. Even if I do include it this way, wont this feature be considered as numerical instead of categorical ?

Comment: The reason to include this is because I do not want the model to rank 2 documents of the same category one after the other.. The training set is also provided in the same way .. So make to the model learn this I want to include this categorical feature.

Comment: you would need to pre-process your data to use the one-hot encoding and yes retrain the model, but its very common practice in machine learning to do this, the model "learns" it as a categorical feature bc the values are either 0 or 1. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot#Machine_learning_and_statistics

Comment: is there any other way? one hot encoding will create 150+ features

Comment: not that I know of, you might be able to use the flattened field type in ES: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/flattened.html#:~:text=The%20flattened%20type%20provides%20an,through%20simple%20queries%20and%20aggregations. to save field space

Comment: Will it work if I combine the one hot encodings something like this 10011 and include it as above?